# Shifting a string in matlab

Tags: matlab

Ok so I have retrieved this string from the text file now I am supposed to shift it by a specified amount. so for example, if the string I retrieved was

> To be, or not to be 
>   That is the question

and the shift number was 5 then the output should be

> stionTo be, or not 
>   to beThat is the que

I was going to use circshift but the given string wouldn't of a matching dimesions. Also the string i would retrieve would be from .txt file.

So here is the code i used

```
S = sprintf('To be, or not to be\nThat is the question')

circshift(S,5,2)
```

but the output is

> stionTo be, or not to be
>   That is the que

but i need

> stionTo be, or not 
>   to beThat is the que

Comment: How is this string stored? Is it a String object? Is it a char array with a newline in it? Is it a cell array of char arrays? What have you tried? Can you show us your code?

Comment: What exactly did you do? `circshift(S,5,2)` works fine for me, where `S = sprintf('To be, or not to be\nThat is the question')`

Comment: No like string would be different everytime so i don't know if circshift gives that output everytime.

Comment: Of course not, but my point was that either a) you used `circshift` in a weird way or b) as beaker also pointed out, you are not using a single string as input. Therefore more code is needed, especially the part where you load the .txt files (and possibly a sample of what's in them).

Comment: What is the desired behavior if a line break ends up needing to be in the middle of a word in order to preserve the dimensionality? Do you want to split the word or move the whole thing to another line?

Comment: Which matlab version are you using? This would be much easier in 2016b or 2017a.

Answer (score 1):

By storing the locations of the new lines, removing the new lines and adding them back in later we can achieve this. This code does rely on the `insertAfter` function which is only available in MATLAB 2016b and later.

```
S = sprintf('To be, or not to be\nThat is the \n question');
newline = regexp(S,'\n');
S(newline) = '';
S = circshift(S,5,2);
for ii = 1:numel(newline)
    S = insertAfter(S,newline(ii)-numel(newline)+ii,'\n');
end
S = sprintf(S);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by performing a circular shift on the indices of the non-newline characters. (The code below actually skips *all* control characters with ASCII code < 32.)

```
function T = strshift(S, k)
   T = S;
   c = find(S >= ' '); % shift only printable characters (ascii code >= 32)
   T(c) = T(circshift(c, k, 2));
end
```

Sample run:

```
>> S = sprintf('To be, or not to be\nThat is the question')

S = To be, or not to be
That is the question

>> r = strshift(S, 5)

r = stionTo be, or not
to beThat is the que
```

If you want to skip *only* the newline characters, just change to

```
c = find(S != 10);
```